# Confused on how to write from a txt file into a string and then convert that into a 2D array

Tags: java

So i'm trying to write in a txt file that looks like this

```
8 7
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 e 1 1
1 0 1 0 0 1 1 
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 
1 0 1 0 1 s 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

and i'm having trouble taking the top two numbers as the size of the array and then converting the rest into a string and then that string into a 2D array with all of those values. Thanks!

```
while (input.hasNext()) {
    numRows = input.nextInt();
    numCols = input.nextInt();

    input.nextLine();

    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
        s = s + input.nextLine();

    int place = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
            maze[numRows][numCols] = String.valueOf(s.charAt(place));
            place++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At least one problem is that you're not iterating over maze. Instead, you're just updating the same place (`maze[numRows][numCols]`) over and over again, which either (1) bugs or (2) throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0):

You're not *indexing*. Use the indexes `i` and `j` you have defined. Here's an example of properly iterating using indices:

> matrix.txt

```
8 7
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 e 1 1
1 0 1 0 0 1 1 
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 
1 0 1 0 1 s 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

> Main.java

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    char[][] matrix = null; // change to String[][] matrix = null; if you want Strings
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(Path.of("matrix.txt"))) {
      int rows = s.nextInt();
      int cols = s.nextInt();
      s.nextLine();
      matrix = new char[rows][cols]; // change to matrix = new String[rows][cols];
      for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
          matrix[i][j] = s.next().charAt(0); // change to matrix[i][j] = s.next();
        }
      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 e 1 1
1 0 1 0 0 1 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 0 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 s 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I've also added suggestions for the case where you'd like a `String[]` instead of a `char[]`.

Comment: Beware: `java.nio.file.Path` is only available in Java 9+

Comment: I think you mean `Path.of()`. `Path` has been around since at least Java 7.

Comment: @Unimportant Weird, I looked in the Java 8 doc and couldn't find it. Edit: Oh, you're right, I'm just blind. :(

Comment: I don't see `Path.of()` _at all_ now that I really look. You have a link for the javadoc?

Comment: @Unimportant I looked in the JDK 10 Javadoc as well and didn't find it. But, I compiled and ran my code on JDK 10. This is super funky. I usually just google "JDK 10 Javadoc" to find it xd

Comment: Yeah, it's not [there](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html). Weird weird weird.